# Queying an API through R and extracting files from it

Tags: r

I am running into a problem while trying to querying publicly available meteorological data from the Dutch Royal Meteorological Institute (KNMI)

Here is my current code:

```
## fetch data from KNMI
url <- 'https://api.dataplatform.knmi.nl/open-data/v1/datasets/Tx1/versions/2/files'

## this key is publicly available directly from KNMI
apikey <- "eyJvcmciOiI1ZTU1NGUxOTI3NGE5NjAwMDEyYTNlYjEiLCJpZCI6ImE1OGI5NGZmMDY5NDRhZDNhZjFkMDBmNDBmNTQyNjBkIiwiaCI6Im11cm11cjEyOCJ9" 

## connect to API
res <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization= apikey))
res
## extract content
tmp <- content(res, as ='text', encoding= "UTF-8") 
tmp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp, flatten = FALSE)
tmp
## ??
```

The output looks like nested lists.
It gives a list of 10 files (the first 10 in their list), however I do not manage to actually 'download' any of them, I do not know what I should write, and I have not found a good answer anywhere so far.

I am trying to get daily maximum temperature from 2010 to 2022 but I really cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to API documentation - https://developer.dataplatform.knmi.nl/get-started - your next request should fetch the URL for a concrete `nc` file, which in turn can be used for downloading:

```r
library(httr)
## fetch data from KNMI
url <- 'https://api.dataplatform.knmi.nl/open-data/v1/datasets/Tx1/versions/2/files/'

## this key is publicly available directly from KNMI
apikey <- "eyJvcmciOiI1ZTU1NGUxOTI3NGE5NjAwMDEyYTNlYjEiLCJpZCI6ImE1OGI5NGZmMDY5NDRhZDNhZjFkMDBmNDBmNTQyNjBkIiwiaCI6Im11cm11cjEyOCJ9" 

## connect to API
res <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = apikey))

# extract content
nc_files <- content(res, simplifyVector = TRUE)$files
tibble::as_tibble(nc_files)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    filename                                                    size lastModified
#>    <chr>                                                      <int> <chr>       
#>  1 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610101T000000_19610102T0000… 531307 2019-12-17T…
#>  2 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610102T000000_19610103T0000… 537877 2019-12-17T…
#>  3 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610103T000000_19610104T0000… 516622 2019-12-17T…
#>  4 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610104T000000_19610105T0000… 529562 2019-12-17T…
#>  5 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610105T000000_19610106T0000… 529055 2019-12-17T…
#>  6 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610106T000000_19610107T0000… 528522 2019-12-17T…
#>  7 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610107T000000_19610108T0000… 531979 2019-12-17T…
#>  8 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610108T000000_19610109T0000… 525359 2019-12-17T…
#>  9 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610109T000000_19610110T0000… 531352 2019-12-17T…
#> 10 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610110T000000_19610111T0000… 536503 2019-12-17T…

# API request to fetch download URL for the 1st nc file:
file_url_req <- paste0(url, nc_files$filename[1], "/url")
file_url_req
#> [1] "https://api.dataplatform.knmi.nl/open-data/v1/datasets/Tx1/versions/2/files/INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610101T000000_19610102T000000_0002.nc/url"
res <- GET(file_url_req, add_headers(Authorization = apikey))
dl_url <- content(res)$temporaryDownloadUrl

# actual download:
download.file(dl_url, destfile = nc_files$filename[1], mode = "wb")
#> ...
#> Content type 'application/x-netcdf' length 531307 bytes (518 KB)
#> downloaded 518 KB

# list downloaded file(s):
fs::dir_info(glob = "*.nc")[,1:3]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   path                                                               type   size
#>   <fs::path>                                                         <fct> <fs:>
#> 1 INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610101T000000_19610102T000000_0002.nc file   519K
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the super quick answer.
I am trying to get my head around this:


the `tmp$files$filename[1]` just fetch directly from the tmp list the first name on that list, correct? and then what does `"/url” does? 


I tried your code and dl_url comes back as `NULL` and therefore the `download.file` does not work. I assume it is because i haven't replaced `$temporaryDownloadUrl` with what it should be. 
I tried replacing it with `file_url_req` but that also led to `NULL`

Comment: @anatase , updated answer should be working without any modifications, you can see initial version here - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76769975/1.  `"/url"` is part of documented API request - https://developer.dataplatform.knmi.nl/apis/64c0caba33d55a00016cb0aa/documentation/ .

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works wonder.
Everything is clear, except for the last few lines. That's for my understanding: 
`dl_url <- content(res)$temporaryDownloadUrl`
`download.file(dl_url, destfile = nc_files$filename[1], mode = "wb")`
`fs::dir_info(glob = "*.nc")[,1:3] `

what is the `temporaryDownloadUrl` call? or is this native to `content`?
And fort he `download.file(...)` the destination is the list ceated earlier, correct? So it's not saved anywhere with this code, only in R, if I may say, is that correct?

Comment: `temporaryDownloadUrl` is part of the API JSON response.  `content(res)`  returns parsed JSON as a list and `content(res)$temporaryDownloadUrl`  just extracts named list item from there. You can see whole parsed response If you execute `content(res)` and/or `str(content(res))` , `download.file()`saves the `nc` file to your working directory and you can continue with `terra::rast("INTER_OPER_R___TX1_____L3__19610101T000000_19610102T000000_0002.nc")`

Comment: `destfile = nc_files$filename[1]` sets the filename for a downloaded file,  1st item from `filename` column of `nc_files` data.frame, i.e. the first file reported by API.